# How can I avoid scoping problems related to React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

### The Problem

I have a recurring problem that seems to happen whenever I try and do anything remotely complicated and async using hooks.

The timeline which causes the issue goes something like this:

1. Define some state in a hook `s`
2. Make an async call to get some data `d` and use it to set state `s`
3. Make a subsequent call based on `d`, and use it to update `s`

The problem is that at 3.; when I want to update the state `s`, it at that point is the `s` as it was defined in the scope at which the function was defined, ie. it has no concept of the latest updated state, only that which it knew about when the function was defined.

### My Half-Solutions

I have been able to get around this using a few things, a couple of things which tend to work:

1. Denormalise state (probably a good idea anyway) such that we avoid as much as possible having to update existing items in state
2. Run the update after an timeout; use `setTimeout` to force the update to happen in the next render cycle
3. Forget using state hooks at all, manage state externally and pass everything in as props

These aren't always (or ever) either good or desirable solutions. I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental here but I haven't been able to find anything about this online, and I haven't yet had any viable suggestions from my colleagues.

### TL:DR

Functions defined within the body of a React functional component will be defined with the scope to which they have access at that time. This isn't always the latest state. How can I get around the problem?

---

### An arbitrary example to demonstrate what it is I'm talking about:

```js
const getUsers = () => Promise.resolve({
  1: {
    name: 'Mr 1',
    favouriteColour: null,
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Ms 2',
    favouriteColour: null,
  },
});

const getFavouriteColorForUser = (id) => Promise.resolve({ id, color: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'red' : 'blue' });


const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState({});
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    getUsers()
      .then(data => {
        setUsers(data);
        return Promise.resolve(data);
      })
      .then(data => {
        return Promise.all(Object.keys(data).map(getFavouriteColorForUser));
      })
      .then(data => {
        const updatedUsers = {
          ...users,
          ...data.reduce(
            (p, c) => ({
              ...p,
              [c.id]: {
                ...users[c.id],
                favouriteColor: c.color
              },
            }),
            {}
          )
        };
        
        console.log('users:');
        console.dir(users);
        console.log('color data:');
        console.dir(data);
        console.log('updatedUsers:');
        console.dir(updatedUsers);
        
        setUsers(updatedUsers);
      })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(users).map(k => users[k]).map(user => (
        <div>{user.name}'s favourite colour is {user.favouriteColour}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Users</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need to return a `Promise` in any `then` callback. Just return the data and it'll be passed to the next step.

Comment: Also note that `setUsers` doesn't change the `users` variable. It just triggers a re-render and in that next render, `users` will be updated accordingly.

Comment: @EmileBergeron re: Promises, when I've tried that before it runs the next `.then` step immediately, I may have been doing something stupid though!

Comment: To make sure you have the latest `users` when calling `setUsers`, use the callback version: `setUsers(prevUsers => /* don't use 'users' here, only 'prevUsers' */)`

Comment: @EmileBergeron re: re-render state; yes indeed, I'm sure you're correct and that's entirely the root of the problem

Comment: _"it runs the next `.then` step immediately"_ that's half true. It always runs async, but it might run sooner, which shouldn't be a problem unless you've set up a race condition, which you want to avoid anyway.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I see, perhaps that was the problem I've seen in the past

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setState has a variant where you pass it a function. That function is guaranteed to be called with the most recent value from the state. You can use that to calculate your next state:

```
.then(data => {
  setUsers(previousUsers => {
    const updatedUsers = {
      ...previousUsers, // <--- using previousUsers, not users
      ...data.reduce(
        (p, c) => ({
          ...p,
          [c.id]: {
            ...previousUsers[c.id], // <--- using previousUsers, not users
            favouriteColor: c.color
          },
        }), {})
    };

    return updatedUsers;
  })
})
```